# How can I assign a click event to an element outside a directive?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-directive

I currently have a custom directive that truncates the text if it's longer than 3 lines. Right now it works if you click directly on the text itself but I would like to assign the click event to a button. This is my current code:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appReadMore]'
})
export class ReadMoreDirective {

  constructor() { }

  @HostBinding('class.truncate-text') get opened() {
    return this.isClosed;
  }
  @HostListener('click') open() {
    this.isClosed = (this.isClosed === true ? false : true);
  }

  private isClosed = true;

}
```

In my html file I have:

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let book of books">
  <div>
    <p appReadMore>
      {{Text 1}}
    </p>
    <p appReadMore>
      {{Text 2}}
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button appReadMoreTrigger>Read more</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my css:

```
.truncate-text {
   overflow: hidden;
   display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

When I click on each individual `<p>` content the `truncate-text` class is applied and removed every other click but I would like that to happen to both `<p>` tags when I click on the Read More button instead.

I tried creating a button directive to set the ReadMoreDirective isClosed value to true/false but it doesn't seem to work correctly (maybe because it's not in the scope of ReadMoreDirective?):

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appReadMoreTrigger]',
})
export class ReadMoreTriggerDirective{

  constructor(private readMore:ReadMoreDirective) {}

  @HostListener('click') open() { 
    this.readMore.open();
  }
}
```

When I try this it throws an error saying "No provider for appReadMoreDirective" and when I do put it in the list of providers, it seems like it creates a new ReadMoreDirective instance.

Thanks

Comment: @isherwood I added the other directive and a small explanation of why it wasn't working for me. It does work when I have the ReadMoreDirective set on a parent div of the ReadMoreTriggerDirective but in this case they are sibling div's.

Comment: Where and how do you add `ReadMoreTriggerDirective` to the DOM? I can't find `appReadMoreTrigger` (the selector of the directive) anywhere in your code.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Sorry I forgot to re-add it to my code above. I added the appReadMoreTrigger selector to the button.

Comment: There are multiple `ReadMoreDirective`s. Which one do you want to address?

Comment: If possible, I would like to activate both of them with one click. So when I click the button, both will open or close.

Comment: There are many ways. How many `appReadMore` could there be? Only 2 or a lot more?

Comment: There will only be two `appReadMore` selectors and one `appReadMoreTrigger` button per item in the `*ngFor` loop.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this on button click event:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[appReadMore]').classList.toggle('truncate-text')
```

Comment: The function should toggle component properties (`isClosed`), not classes. That's not "the Angular way".

Comment: Yeah, but the button is not in the scope of the directive. Anyway, I was just trying to help